# Как создать бесплатный товар

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, настройка

Как в woocommerce бесплатно разрешить скачать файл авторизованному клиенту?

Товар электронный и есть пару товаров которые хочу чтобы клиенты бесплатно скачали.

Answer (score 4):

Создайте на этот товар купон со скидкой 100% и сообщите код купона нужным клиентам.

Comment: Ну а нет вариантов авторизованному клиенту, просто дать ссылку для скачивания без скидок и купонов?

Comment: Таких вариантов нет. Ну разве что просто дать прямую ссылку на файл. Но зачем тогда WooCommerce? Купон устанавливает ограничения на доступность (только тем, кто знает код) и на количество скачиваний (опционально).

Comment: Как сделать так, чтобы скажем некоторые шаблоны были доступны всем для скачивания?, а остальные: 'Премиум', платные.

Comment: Поставьте цену 0